How to Capture RAW Format Images with Camera2Interop
I'm trying to capture a raw image from CameraX with Camera2Interop.
I understand how to use the methods of Camera2Interop.Extender.
However, I have no idea whether to use ImageCapture.takePicture() of CameraX or ImageCaptureSession.capture() of Camera2 to start a capture.
I'm currently experimenting with the latter because ImageReader can set ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR but,
However, I can't connect ImageReader to CameraCaptureSession and CaptureReqeust that CameraX has internally.
I'm not sure if it's the right approach.
Could anyone provide guidance?
